# What is the best way to use tr and grep on a folder?

Tags: grep

I'm trying to search through all files in a folder for the following string

```
<cert>
</cert>
```

However, I have to remove line returns.
The following code works on one file but how can I pipe an entire folder through the tr and grep? The -l option is to only print the filename and not the whole file.

```
 tr -d '\n' < test | grep -l '<cert></cert>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `tr`/`grep` approach requires `grep` to process the whole file as one line.  While GNU `grep` can handle long lines, many others cannot.  Also, if the file is large, memory may be taxed.

The following avoids those issues.  It searches through all files in the currect directory and report names of any that contain `<cert>` on one line and `</cert>` on the next:

```
awk 'last ~ "<cert>" && $0 ~ "</cert>" {print FILENAME; nextfile} {last=$0}' *
```

#### How it works

awk implicitly loops over all lines in a file.

This script uses one variable, `last`, which contains the text of the previous line.

- `last ~ "<cert>"` && $0 ~ ""`

  This tests if (a) the last line contains the characters `<cert>` and (b) the current line contains the characters `</cert>`.

  If you actually wanted lines that contain `<cert>` and no other characters, then replace `~` with `==`.
- `{print FILENAME; nextfile}`

  If the preceding condition returns true, then this prints the file's name and starts on the next file.

  (`nextfile` was a [common extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html) to awk that became POSIX 2012.)
- `{last=$0}`

  This updates the variable `last` to have the current line.